# spring with javafx application exception when load fxml after mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx, fxml

Without mapping fxml this code run perfectly and load fxml

if i map fxml getting exception 
i try alot but unable to understand what is the problem.....

SpringFxmlLoader class method load() return statement not returning anything because of which i think exception occur

> javafx.fxml.LoadException:/E:/aa/JavaFXwithSpringBoot/bin/test/spring/boot/LoginPage.fxml:15
>
> at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579) at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441) at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409) at
>   test.spring.boot.config.SpringFXMLLoader.load(SpringFXMLLoader.java:34)
>   at
>   test.spring.boot.config.StageManager.loadViewNodeHierarchy(StageManager.java:80)
>   at
>   test.spring.boot.config.StageManager.switchScene(StageManager.java:31)
>   at test.spring.boot.Main.displayInitialScene(Main.java:35) at
>   test.spring.boot.Main.start(Main.java:24) at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'test.spring.boot.LoginPageController'
>   available at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
>   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:929)
>   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
>   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
>   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707) at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527) ... 16 more
>   Exception in Application start method 2017-10-24 17:18:03.779 ERROR
>   6416 --- [lication Thread] test.spring.boot.config.StageManager     :
>   Unable to load FXML view >> /test/spring/boot/LoginPage.fxml
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'test.spring.boot.LoginPageController'
>   available at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE] at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:929)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527) ~[jfxrt.jar:na]
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at
>   test.spring.boot.config.SpringFXMLLoader.load(SpringFXMLLoader.java:34)
>   ~[bin/:na] at
>   test.spring.boot.config.StageManager.loadViewNodeHierarchy(StageManager.java:80)
>   [bin/:na] at
>   test.spring.boot.config.StageManager.switchScene(StageManager.java:31)
>   [bin/:na] at test.spring.boot.Main.displayInitialScene(Main.java:35)
>   [bin/:na] at test.spring.boot.Main.start(Main.java:24) [bin/:na] at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>   [jfxrt.jar:na] at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131] at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
>   Method) ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>   ~[jfxrt.jar:na] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>
> 2017-10-24 17:18:03.846  INFO 6416 --- [lication Thread] 
>   s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@f096164:
>   startup date [Tue Oct 24 17:18:02 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   2017-10-24 17:18:03.848  INFO 6416 --- [lication Thread]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed
>   beans on shutdown java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.(Scene.java:336) at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.(Scene.java:194) at
>   test.spring.boot.config.StageManager.prepareScene(StageManager.java:62)
>   at test.spring.boot.config.StageManager.show(StageManager.java:36) at
>   test.spring.boot.config.StageManager.switchScene(StageManager.java:32)
>   at test.spring.boot.Main.displayInitialScene(Main.java:35) at
>   test.spring.boot.Main.start(Main.java:24) at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>   ... 1 more Exception running application test.spring.boot.Main

Main.java

```
@ComponentScan("test.spring.boot")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends Application {

    protected ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    protected StageManager stageManager;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        stageManager = springContext.getBean(StageManager.class, primaryStage);
        displayInitialScene();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception
    {
        springContext=springBootApplicationContext();
    }


    protected void displayInitialScene() {
        stageManager.switchScene(FxmlView.LOGIN);
    }


     @Override
     public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.close();
     }

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springBootApplicationContext() {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class);
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().stream().toArray(String[]::new);
        return builder.run(args);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
public class LoginPageController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUserName;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField txtPassward;

    @FXML
    private Button btnLogin;

    @FXML
    private Label lblLogin; 

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private StageManager stageManager;

    @FXML
    public void login()
    {
        if(userService.authenticate(txtUserName.getText(), txtPassward.getText()))
        {
            stageManager.switchScene(FxmlView.USER);
        }
        else
        {
            lblLogin.setText("Login Failed.");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
}
```

FxmlView.java

```
public enum FxmlView {
    USER {
        @Override
        public String getTitle() {
            return getStringFromResourceBundle("user.title");
        }

        @Override
        public String getFxmlFile() {
            return "/test/spring/boot/TestSpring.fxml";
        }
    }, 


    LOGIN {
        @Override
        public String getTitle() {
            return getStringFromResourceBundle("login.title");
        }

        @Override
        public String getFxmlFile() {
            return "/test/spring/boot/LoginPage.fxml";
        }
    };

    public abstract String getTitle();
    public abstract String getFxmlFile();

    String getStringFromResourceBundle(String key){
        return ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle").getString(key);
    }
}
```

SpringFxmlLoader.java

```
@Component
public class SpringFXMLLoader {
    private final ResourceBundle resourceBundle;
    private final ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    public SpringFXMLLoader(ApplicationContext context, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        this.resourceBundle = resourceBundle;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Parent load(String fxmlPath) throws IOException {      
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean); //Spring now FXML Controller Factory
        loader.setResources(resourceBundle);
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
        System.out.println("springfxmlloader class : "+fxmlPath);
        System.out.println("LOADER : ");
        return loader.load();
    }
}
```

StageManager.java

```
public class StageManager {

 private static final Logger LOG = getLogger(StageManager.class);
    private final Stage primaryStage;
    private final SpringFXMLLoader springFXMLLoader;

    public StageManager(SpringFXMLLoader springFXMLLoader, Stage stage) {

    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 1");

        this.springFXMLLoader = springFXMLLoader;
        this.primaryStage = stage;
    }

    public void switchScene(final FxmlView view) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 2");
        Parent viewRootNodeHierarchy = loadViewNodeHierarchy(view.getFxmlFile());
        show(viewRootNodeHierarchy, view.getTitle());
    }

    private void show(final Parent rootnode, String title) {
        Scene scene = prepareScene(rootnode);
        //scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

        //primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setTitle(title);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 3");

        try {
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logAndExit ("Unable to show scene for title" + title,  exception);
        }
    }

    private Scene prepareScene(Parent rootnode){

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 4");
        Scene scene = primaryStage.getScene();

        System.out.println("SCN >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : "+ scene);

        if (scene == null) {
            scene = new Scene(rootnode);
        }
        scene.setRoot(rootnode);
        return scene;
    }


    private Parent loadViewNodeHierarchy(String fxmlFilePath) {

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 5 path: "+fxmlFilePath);
        Parent rootNode = null;
        try {
            System.out.println(fxmlFilePath);
            rootNode = springFXMLLoader.load(fxmlFilePath);
            System.out.println(">>>>5 : try");
            Objects.requireNonNull(rootNode, "A Root FXML node must not be null");
        } catch (Exception exception) {

            System.out.println("File path????? : "+fxmlFilePath);

            logAndExit("Unable to load FXML view >> " + fxmlFilePath, exception);
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rootNode;
    }


    private void logAndExit(String errorMsg, Exception exception) {

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 6");
        LOG.error(errorMsg, exception, exception.getCause());
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a couple of problems: You can't load that fxml file and there's a missing Spring Bean.  Check the path on the load; the exception should give you a hint.

Comment: @duffymo   can you please help me with spring bean file coz i'm new.....can you please share some use full links where i get to know how to create spring bean....thankyou

Comment: Dude, I can't help you learn Spring in this forum.  Get with their docs and dig in.  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'test.spring.boot.LoginPageController' available.  Find the JAR with that bean and add it to your project.  The path /E:/aa/JavaFXwithSpringBoot/bin/test/spring/boot/LoginPage.fxml:15 is a problem.

Comment: @duffymo Okay! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add a [Stereotype](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/package-summary.html) on your `LoginPageController` class that's why Spring is telling you:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'test.spring.boot.LoginPageController'
```

As the class is not marked the component-scan will ignore it and there will be no bean register assignable for that type.

Try:

```
@Controller
public class LoginPageController implements Initializable{

    @Autowired
    public LoginPageController(UserService userService, private StageManager stageManager){
        this.userService = userService;
        this.stageManager = stageManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it but still getting same exception..........actually exception creating confusion that exception raise because of jar or code

Comment: thank you! you are right problem is coz of sterotype. thankyou for your time